# Openlayers2 - Increase icons size?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I built a small Openlayers/GeoServer application. I'm trying to change the size of the `LayerSwitcher` icon "+" (right) and the one of the standard zoom icon (left). I tried to modify CSS but can't increase theirs sizes in order that they could be used easily when displayed on the screen of a mobile phone where they are very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the TouchNavigation control which is specially designed for mobiles:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/TouchNavigation-js.html
- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-navigation.html

Answer (score 4):

For zoom I'd recommend using the new Zoom control, whose UI can be customized using CSS. See http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Zoom-js.html and http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/zoom.html. This control is not in the current stable release (2.11). It is in the development branch and will be available in the next release.